Azure Mapping JSON - convert empty string or whitespace cells from CSV's to null
I'm importing multiple addressbase CSV files that don't have headers via Azure Synapse and ADLS so using MAPPING_JSON in an ETL.Process table with SQL Server Management Studio 20.1.10.0.
That part is fine but I'm struggling to convert the blank cells into NULLS (to save me amending matching code for addresses on other systems) which I'm hoping to do via the JSON at import. Few hours googling and countless attempts which all run but I'm not sure if I've got the null clause in the right place or whether the 'column' part needs changing as they still produce blank cells instead of nulls...solution would be much appreciated, example attached
{
  "type": "TabularTranslator",
  "mappings": [
    {
      "source": {
        "type": "String",
        "ordinal": 1
      },
      "sink": {
        "name": "UPRN",
        "physicalType": "iif(toString(length(rtrim(Column))) > 0, Column,toString(null()))"
      }
    },
    {
      "source": {
        "type": "String",
        "ordinal": 2
      },
      "sink": {
        "name": "OS_ADDRESS_TOID",
        "physicalType": "iif(toString(length(rtrim(Column))) > 0, Column,toString(null()))"
      }
    }
  ],
  "typeConversion": true,
  "typeConversionSettings": {
    "allowDataTruncation": true,
    "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
  }
}

Current Output Image

Could you please provide sample json?

{ "type": "TabularTranslator", "mappings": [ { "source": { "type": "String", "ordinal": 1 }, "sink": { "name": "UPRN", "physicalType":"iif(toString(length(rtrim(Column))) > 0, Column,toString(null()))" } }, { "source": { "type": "String", "ordinal": 2 }, "sink": { "name": "OS_ADDRESS_TOID", "physicalType":"iif(toString(length(rtrim(Column))) > 0, Column,toString(null()))" } } ], "typeConversion": true, "typeConversionSettings": { "allowDataTruncation": true, "treatBooleanAsNumber": false } }

I’ve tried to take column 1 for example name it UPRN then when ingesting the data count the length of the cell and if it’s greater than 0 then return the value but if not then return null.So far, no joy

@TSdeveloper  can you try the iif(toString(length(rtrim(Column))) != "0", Column,toString(null()))

Same output unfortunately, the empty cells still come through as blank whitespace instead of nulls. Link to output image is above:  https://i.sstatic.net/wiDtKvvY.png

In the Azure synapse the character used to specify the string representation of null value. The default value is empty string.
I have tried the below:
@string('')


In the above Blank values from the source are treated as NULL values in the SQL Server.
For example I have used below as the sample data:
xtz,col2,col3
,5,ok
j,,


And I tried the below
SELECT  *  FROM [dbo].[ok3] where id is  null;

Results:

Which gives the values for NULL values:
Now If you want to replace NULL  Value to your desired text you have to make it in the SQL server.
I have tried the below:
SELECT
id,
CASE
WHEN id IS  NULL  THEN  '(The is blank)'
ELSE id
END  AS T1
FROM [dbo].[ok3]

Results:

